# this is right code to validate a field

Tags: javascript

Name:
            
            
 Email:
            
            
 Password:

```
var invalid = 0;

function validation() {
    invalid = 0;
    if (document.getElementById("name").value == "") 
    {
        document.getElementById("invalid_1").innerHTMl = "you must type your name";
        invalid += 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        document.getElementById("invalid_1").innerHTMl = "";
    }

    if (invalid != 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I use this code for validate my field, but this code was not working yet. What is wrong?

Comment: describe the nature of your problem. In what way does it not work? Any console errors to report?

Comment: can you tell me what you want to do?..show me your full code with html

Comment: ok i will share my html code

Comment: <form name="survey"  method="post" onsubmit="return validation()">
        <fieldset>
            Name:
            <input type="text" size="20" id="name">
            <br> Email:
            <input type="text" size="20" id="email">
            <br> Password:
            <input type="password" size="16" id="password">
            <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
            <input type="reset" name="reset">
            <br>
            <br>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <p id="invalid_1"> </p>

Comment: @punit1290 :- you want to validate textbox empty or not? or something else?

Comment: Please correct your question to include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @darshak-gajjar:- yes

Comment: Please don't provide code in comments, [edit] your question to provide the relevant details directly in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You got typo. put `innerHTML` instead of `innerHTMl`

Answer (score 1):

There are several good approaches to validate a field. I would recommend not trying to create the wheel but use something already implemented.
I present to you the [Parsley library](http://parsleyjs.org/). Is a library created for validate fields and forms.

From their demo site:

-Validating a group on inputs -

```
<h4>Correctly fill at least one of these blocks</h4>
<form class="demo-form">
  <div data-parsley-check-children="2" data-parsley-validate-if-empty="">
    <div class="first">
      <label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" data-parsley-length="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block-1">

      <label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" data-parsley-length="[4, 20]" data-parsley-group="block-1">
    </div>

    <hr>

    <div class="second">
      <label for="fullname">Fullname:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" data-parsley-length="[8, 40]" data-parsley-group="block-2">
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default validate">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  Parsley.addValidator('checkChildren', {
    messages: {en: 'You must correctly fill at least one of these blocks!'},
    requirementType: 'integer',
    validate: function(_value, requirement, instance) {
      for(var i = 1; i <= requirement; i++)
        if (instance.parent.isValid({group: 'block-' + i, force: true}))
          return true; // One section is filled, this check is valid
      return false; // No section is filled, this validation fails
    }
  });

  Parsley.on('form:submit', function() {
    alert("The form would be submitted at this point. " +
      "For this demo, we interrupt the processing.");
    return false; // Don't submit for this demo
  });

  $('.demo-form').parsley({
    inputs: Parsley.options.inputs + ',[data-parsley-check-children]'
  });
});
</script>
```

You can check this code here: [parsley example](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/custom-validator-events.html)

Answer (score 1):

You should use innerHTML instead of innerHTMl ( L also be capital).
and instead of giving onsubmit to form, use onclick to submit button

```js
function validation() {
  if (document.getElementById("name").value.length == 0) {
        document.getElementById("invalid_1").innerHTML = 
                                   "you must type your name";
        return false;
  } 
  else {
        document.getElementById("invalid_1").innerHTML = "";
        return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="survey" method="post"> 
  <fieldset> Name: <input type="text" size="20" id="name"> <br />
             Email: <input type="text" size="20" id="email"> <br />          
             Password: <input type="password" size="16" id="password">           
             <br /> <br /> 
             <input type="submit" onclick="return validation()"
                    value="submit"> 
             <input type="reset" name="reset"> 
             <br /> <br /> 
  </fieldset> 
</form> 

<p id="invalid_1"></p>
```

Comment: :- Thanks for help.